# Which number should replace the question mark?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

There is a picture. Find out what number is needed to replace this question mark.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 41

because

> Each number in the third row is the difference of the product and sum of the numbers in the same column of the first and second rows.
>  i.e. $C = A\times B -(A+B)$
>
>  $5\times7 - (5+7) = 35 - 12 = 23$
>  $12\times9 - (12+9) = 108 - 21 = 87$
>
>  $15\times4 - (15+4) = 60 - 19 = 41$

Answer (score 1):

I found <s>the same answer as @Apep's, but in a different way</s> a different answer.

> $?=17$

> For some $x$, let $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$. This is the notation I will be using for the following pattern.

> The first column has $5$, $7$ and lastly $|23|$. $$23+1\times |5-7|=5^2\tag{$\times 1$ since it is the $1^\text{st}$ column}$$ $5$ is the lowest out of $5$ and $7$. 
>  
>  The second column has $12$, $9$ and lastly $|87|$. $$87-2\times |12-9|=9^2\tag{$\times 2$ since it is the $2^\text{nd}$ column}$$ $9$ is the lowest out of $12$ and $9$. 
>  
>  Note that since *this* column has a minus instead of a plus, then the overall pattern is therefore going to have alternating signs, implying that the following column will have a plus sign.

Therefore:

> In the third column, if we let the question mark be $\rm A$ for *Answer*, then it is going to look like this: $$\rm{A}+3\times|15-4|=4^2$$ Since $\rm A = -17$, then in the last number of the third column, the answer is going to be $|$$-17|$ which is $17$.

> Having the inclusion of $|\cdot |$ allows there to be no negative numbers.